# Flex load modules READY event not fired, why?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, module

Hello I have this very simple mxml example.

Using flex builder with flex sdk 3.4.0 if the module is remote like http://edofiles.s3.amazonaws.com/calculator.swf

The READY event is never fired, i don't understand why.

Do  you get the same behavior ?

Original code is from http://lowpitch.com/blog/modulemanager-and-imoduleinfo-loading-flex-modules-dynamically/#comment-4396

Any clues ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    applicationComplete="initApp()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.modules.Module;
            import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
            import mx.modules.ModuleManager;
            import mx.modules.IModuleInfo;

          protected var _moduleInfo:IModuleInfo;

            private function initApp():void {
               addToLog ("Application initialised");
               // create the module - note, we're not loading it yet
                _moduleInfo = ModuleManager.getModule("http://edofiles.s3.amazonaws.com/calculator.swf");
               // add some listeners
               _moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, onModuleReady);
               _moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.SETUP, onModuleSetup);
               _moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.UNLOAD, onModuleUnload);
               _moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.PROGRESS, onModuleProgress);
            }

            protected function getModuleInfo () : IModuleInfo {
               // return the module info
               return _moduleInfo;
            }

            /**
             * Adds output to the log
             **/
            protected function addToLog (msg:String) : void {
                log.text += msg + "\n";
                // scroll to the bottom on the next frame
                callLater(scrollToBottom);

            }

            protected function scrollToBottom () : void {
                // scroll to the bottom
                log.verticalScrollPosition = log.maxVerticalScrollPosition;
            }

            /**
            * Called when the "load" button is pressed
            *
            * Starts loading the module - when the module has been
            * loaded, an instance of the module will be created
            * and added to the tile control
            *
            **/
            private function loadModule () : void {
                addToLog ("Loading module");
                // load the module
                getModuleInfo().load();
            }

            /**
             * Called when the "unload" button is pressed
             *
             * Removes all the instances of the module from the
             * tile control, then unloads the module
             *
             */
            private function unloadModule () : void {
                addToLog ("Unloading module");
                // clear out all the the instances
                // of the module from the tile
                tile.removeAllChildren();
                // unload the module
                getModuleInfo().release();
                //getModuleInfo().un
            }

            /**
            * Handler for the ModuleEvent.PROGRESS event
            **/
            protected function onModuleProgress (e:ModuleEvent) : void {
                addToLog ("ModuleEvent.PROGRESS received: " + e.bytesLoaded + " of " + e.bytesTotal + " loaded.");
            }

            /**
            * Handler for the ModuleEvent.SETUP event
            **/
            private function onModuleSetup (e:ModuleEvent) : void {
                addToLog ("ModuleEvent.SETUP received");
                // cast the currentTarget
                var moduleInfo:IModuleInfo = e.currentTarget as IModuleInfo;
                addToLog ("Calling IModuleInfo.factory.info ()");
                // grab the info and display information about it
                var info:Object = moduleInfo.factory.info();
                for (var each:String in info) {
                    addToLog ("     " + each + " = " + info[each]);
                }

            }

            /**
            * Handler for the ModuleEvent.READY event
            **/
            private function onModuleReady (e:ModuleEvent):void {
                addToLog ("ModuleEvent.READY received");
                // cast the currentTarget
                var moduleInfo:IModuleInfo = e.currentTarget as IModuleInfo;
                // Add an instance of the module's class to the
                // display list.
                addToLog ("Calling IModuleInfo.factory.create ()");
                tile.addChild( moduleInfo.factory.create () as Module);
                addToLog ("SomeModule instance created and added to Display List");
            }

            /**
            * Handler for the ModuleEvent.UNLOAD event
            **/
            public function onModuleUnload (e:ModuleEvent) : void {
                addToLog ("ModuleEvent.UNLOAD received");
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Tile id="tile" width="100%" height="100%" />
           <mx:TextArea id="log" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </mx:HBox>


    <mx:ApplicationControlBar>
        <mx:Button label="Load" click="loadModule ()" />
        <mx:Button label="Unload" click="unloadModule ()"/>
    </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: you can try addEventListener on null info, see what happen

Answer (score 3):

I had this behavior today. Even though it's not directly related to what the poster asked, this topic comes up pretty high in google search, so I want to help out others who stumble here.

I found the solution at the following blog:
http://www.joshuaostrom.com/2008/08/14/flex-modules-watch-your-scope/

The problem is that ModuleLoader automatically garbage collects when you call `load()`, so if you're not extra careful with your references, your listeners can get destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be simple and funny. Try taht: first addEventListener code, next getModule().

Answer (score 0):

it can also happen because you try to load a module compiled for release with an application compiled for debug.  This has happened to me before.  both app and modules must match debug/debug or release/release.

if they do not match, you will get progress events, and "setup" events, but never a ready event.